# Research in psychiatry

Tags: etymology

My  research is not linguistics pers se, it is placed in psychiatry, and my problem and question is the French etymology concerning the word psychiatry in French

Comment: psychiatrie, from Medieval Latin psychiatria, literally "a healing of the soul," from Latinized form of Greek psykhē "mind" (see psyche) + iatreia "healing, care" (see -iatric). https://www.etymonline.com/word/psychiatry

Comment: Very grateful, well be of use in my Swedish writings

Answer (score 3):

The English word comes from the French, which comes from a Mediaeval Latin invention: a combination of *psych-* (from Greek for "soul"), *-iatr-* (from Greek for "doctor"), and *-ia* (indicating a general process). Literally, medical treatment for the soul.

Comment: This was I verry good answer to me, Now the problem left is only when the word psychiatry was borrowed into use in Germany, as in the writings of Johann Christian Reil, more then two hundred years ago. That would be a question too. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @LeifRasmusson If you find an answer useful, remember you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left!